# div background-image inside table cell does not work on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<table class="pricetable">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #E6E6E6 !important;">

<td rowspan="4" class="iti">
<div class="itemTableImage" style="background: url(http://www.storagerealm.com/images/intel-ssd-520.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
</td>

<th>Capacity</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
<td class="cell1">128 GB</td>
<td class="cell2">$129.99</td>

</tr>
<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
<td class="cell1">256 GB</td>
<td class="cell2">$229.37</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">512 GB</td>
<td class="cell2">$444.99</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and CSS is:

```
.pricetable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 275px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em auto 1em; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing:5px 5px;
}

.iti {
    width: 275px;
    background-color: #FBF5EF;
}

div.itemTableImage {
    width: 97%;
    height: 97%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

I'm pleased by the result on Chrome, Safari and Opera, but Firefox and IE does not view the image of the product.

Here what I get as a result on Chrome:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/35hgxuq.jpg

and this what I get on Firefox:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/ra3vo4.jpg

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: did  you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-image:` instead of `background:`

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the background properties separately:

```
background-image: url(http://www.storagerealm.com/images/intel-ssd-520.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
<td rowspan="4" class="iti">
<div class="itemTableImage" style="background: url(http://www.storagerealm.com/images/intel-ssd-520.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
</td>
```

with

```
<td rowspan="4"  class="itemTableImage" style="background: url(http://www.storagerealm.com/images/intel-ssd-520.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;width: 275px; background-color: #FBF5EF; ">
```

i have tested it displays image in both crome and firefox

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before already but I wanted an image smaller than its container (i.e. the td) and that the shadow surrounds the image not the container. That's why I went for div inside td. Can you help please?